# How to SUM each column in this dynamically created table like excel

Tags: php, jquery

I'll try my best to explain my current problem.

I've created a view, something like excel. It's dynamically created. (see below)

```
  A     B       C
| 1|   | 3|   | 7|       // The input format is `<input type='text' class='inputitem' id='colA_row1' />`
| 2|   | 6|   | 8|       // The `id` of this `inputitem`is defined by the number of columns and rows automatically
| 9|   | 7|   | 4|

|12|   |16|   |19|       // The format of total textbox is `<input type='text' class='totalitem' id='total_colA' />           
                         //// The `id` of this `totalitem` is defined by the number of column automatically
```

User may input any number to any `inputitem` and the value of `totalitem` is adjusted to the SUM of value in each column. (in example, if user change the value of column A row 2 to 9, the `totalcolumn` of column A is changed into 19)

This is my current jquery code:

```
$('.inputitem').on('keyup', function(){
        var _inputitem      = $(this);            
        var _inputitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var _inputitem_col  = _inputitem_arr[0];
        var _inputitem_row  = _inputitem_arr[1];            

        /*SUM SCRIPT*/
        var sum_item = 0;
        $('.inputitem').each(function(i){

            var inputitem_val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', ''));

            $('.totalitem').each(function(i){
                var _totalitem      = $(this);
                var _totalitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
                var _totalitem_col  = _totalitem_arr[1];                                   

                if(_inputitem_col == _totalitem_col){
                        sum_item = sum_item + inputitem_val;

                        _totalitem.val(sum_item);
                }
            });
        });     
        /*END SUM SCRIPT*/
});
```

My current script give wrong value of total item. It seems to adding the SUM of different column into the formula. Any help and suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the flow of this code.
Your outermost function executes when the user finishes a key press (keyup event) on any input element on your page that has class "input item". So far, so good.

You initialize the sum to 0 and then you call
    $('.inputitem').each(function(i){

This call means that for *every* element on the page that has class "input item", you will run the entire script inside the inner function. So for the first inputitem (perhaps the one in the top left, perhaps not) we get the value 1.0 in inputitem_val.

Here's where the trouble really starts. Next you call the each function for all of your total cells. But this is a *nested* call. So you are doing that inner-most function anew for each of the 9 (or however many) cells of your outer each loop. Here's a fix un-nests the functions:

```
$('.inputitem').on('keyup', function(){
    var _inputitem      = $(this);            
    var _inputitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var _inputitem_col  = _inputitem_arr[0];

    //whichever column this cell is in is the column we need to re-sum
    var active_col = _inputitem_col


    /*SUM SCRIPT*/
    var sum_item = 0;

    //iterate through each input cell
    $('.inputitem').each(function(i){
        var _inputitem      = $(this);            
        var _inputitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var _inputitem_col  = _inputitem_arr[0];

        //check whether the current input cell is in the active column
        if(_inputitem_col == active_col){
            //if so, add it to our partial sum
            var inputitem_val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', ''));
            sum_item += inputitem_val;
        }
    });     

    //find and update only the relavent sum cell
    $('.totalitem').each(function(i){
        var _totalitem      = $(this);
        var _totalitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var _totalitem_col  = _totalitem_arr[1];                                   

        if(_inputitem_col == _totalitem_col){
            _totalitem.val(sum_item);
        }
    });
    /*END SUM SCRIPT*/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.inputitem').on('keyup', function(){
    var _inputitem_arr  = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var _inputitem_col  = _inputitem_arr[0];
    var $totlaSelector  = '#total_' + _inputitem_col;
    var $ColTotal = 0;

    $('[id^="'+_inputitem_col+'"]').each(function(i){
       var $thisVal = 0;
       if($(this).val() != ''){
        $thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
       }
       $ColTotal = $ColTotal + $thisVal;
    });

    $($totlaSelector).val($ColTotal);
});
```

I have updated your jQuery on keyup event.